# Android SDK missing proguard and zipAlign

Tags: android, jenkins, cloudbees

Using Android SDK 23.0.2 on CloudBees build servers - I see build errors with proguard and zipAlign.

Both proguard and zipalign are missing from that version of the Android SDK.

see [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72400)

How do I get this working for my build?

Answer (score 1):

Solution - download an older Android SDK and copy these tools from it.

The following script can be used as step before your main build runs - which will conditionally download and obtain those tools: (see [here](https://gist.github.com/michaelneale/886f47825fc5e5a36ef0))

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ ! -d /opt/android/android-sdk-linux/tools/proguard ]
then
    echo "Downloading SDK directory for Proguard"
    curl -O http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r22.6.2-linux.tgz
    tar -zxvf android-sdk_r22.6.2-linux.tgz
    echo "Copying proguard directory..."
    cp -r android-sdk-linux/tools/proguard /opt/android/android-sdk-linux/tools
fi

if [ ! -f /opt/android/android-sdk-linux/tools/zipalign ]
then
    if [ ! -f android-sdk_r22.6.2-linux.tgz ]
    then
        echo "Downloading SDK directory for zipalign"
        curl -O http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r22.6.2-linux.tgz
        tar -zxvf android-sdk_r22.6.2-linux.tgz
    fi
    echo "Copying zipalign file..."
    if [ -h /opt/android/android-sdk-linux/tools/zipalign ]
    then
        rm -rf /opt/android/android-sdk-linux/tools/zipalign
    fi
    cp android-sdk-linux/tools/zipalign /opt/android/android-sdk-linux/tools
fi

if [ -d android-sdk-linux ]
then
    echo "Removing downloaded SDK directory and TGZ"
    rm -rf android-sdk-linux
    rm -f android-sdk_r22.6.2-linux.tgz
fi
```